# Odoo 14 in Docker: Database connection failure: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: docker, odoo, odoo-14

I'm running Odoo 14 in a Docker container, linked to another container with PostgreSQL. I've had this setup for a month now, but yesterday I noticed that the Odoo container kept restarting every minute. According to the log:

```
Database connection failure: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Is the server running on host "172.17.0.3" and accepting

TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

As far as I can tell, the server is indeed running on that IP address and port - I'm using Docker's bridge network. Besides, it's not like I've made any changes to the environment since Odoo was first set up.

Both containers are running on a Synology NAS and were set up using the Synology Docker GUI. Below are the seetings for the Odoo container (odoo-app) and the PostgreSQL container (odoo-postgres):

[image: PostgreSQL]

[image: Odoo]

Can anyone help me understand what's wrong and how to sort it out?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide your docker network configuration. How did you setup PostgreSQL user for odoo. And odoo configuration or command line arguments for database connection.

Comment: I've edited my original post with screenshots of the Docker settings for both containers. Essentially, the PostgreSQL container has environmental variables with the user/DB/password and the Odoo container is linked to the fomer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that, because I had opted for the "latest" Postgres container, a recent update might have knocked things out of balance.

I've just successfully restored the initial setup with Odoo 14 and PostgreSQL 13.